# Real COM Port vs Virtual COM port

Tags: gps, serial-port, google-earth, nmea

GPS NMEA data when sent to virtual serial port pair (created using fabula virtual serial port kit) is plotted on Google earth using the real-time option available under Tools/GPS/GPS-Import menu. The results are satisfactory. The same setup when tested using a null modem cable( full handshaking) between two terminals, gives a negative result. The baud rate is kept constant at 9600 in both cases.
Could someone please tell what's the problem?

Comment: what do you mean with negative result. The communication simply does now work?

Comment: Yeah - you need to isolate the differences. A virtual serial port *should* act like the legacy serial port, however vendors can mess this up and there are plenty of corner cases that cause problems. I don't know your platform, but if it's a supported version of Windows look at [PortMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx), this will let you see the differences in the serial protocol. If you are using another OS please provide more info on the failure - codes, failing code snippet, etc.